# Change a function's properties each time it's executed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm willing to create a function that changes *payhighx()* into *paylowx()* and *paylowx()* into *payhighx()* each time one of the two is executed. I thought of an if statement going into the *roll()* function that'd check whether *payhighx()/paylowx()* was executed and change their properties if the returned value is *True*. I tried researching something related to my problem, but couldn't find anything useful in terms of JQuery and Javascript.

```
var start = 0.01

var $input = $("#oddsInput")
var $odds = $("#oddsOverUnder")
var $button = $("#roll")
var $bet = $("#bet")
var $pay = $("#oddsPayout.btn.btn-primary.btn-xlg.btn-block")

function paylowx() {
    $pay.click()
    document.getElementById("oddsInput").value = "1.2";
    $odds.click()
}

function payhighx() {
    $pay.click()
    document.getElementById("oddsInput").value = "5.2";
    $odds.click()
}

function roll() {
    $bet.val(start)
    $button.click()
    setTimeout(function() {
        var tr = document.querySelector("#myBetsTable tr:nth-child(2)")
        var cls = tr.getAttribute('class')
        if (cls === 'success'){

        }
        else{
            payhighx()
        }
            $button.click();
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $button.click();
            },1000);
            },1000);
}

setInterval(roll, 2000)
```

Comment: you dont actually need 2 functions

Comment: Are you suggesting an alternating function that changes its properties once it's been executed?

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear, but it sounds like you just need a single function, payx(), with its own flag to know whether it paid high or low last time. There are a few ways to do that, but I don't want to get too carried away writing them up when I'm not sure that I've understood what you want to do.

Comment: in javascript, you can assign property to function itself inside function, like `function payx() {(payx.toggle = !payx.toggle) ? doThis() : doThat()}`

Comment: I haven't looked at the problem from this perspective, @nnnnnn, and yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Still can't get my head around it